# Count number of words in range of cells separated by "-" in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

i'm having some issues with a formula to count number of words in a range of cells separated by "-".

The formula that I have is working but if the cells are empty, it still shows "1" instead of "0".

Formula : `=COUNTA(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(D16:G16&CHAR(45)));CHAR(45)))`

It also works for 2 ranges of cells but not 3. If anyone can help me out it'll be apreciated !
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SPLIT` is returning an error, which counts as a non-empty cell.

Add an `IFERROR` to handle the error. You can also use `TEXTJOIN` instead of `CONCATENATE`.

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(45),1,D16:G16)),CHAR(45))))
```